# How is the external force and the tension force related in this system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

Two bodies, A and B, are connected by a string. The string is **massless**, **inextensible,** and is always **tight**. Also, the surface they are on is **frictionless**. There is an external force $F_{applied}$ acting on block B, shown by the red vector. And the *tension* forces acting the two bodies have been shown by pink vectors. Of course the two pink vectors, *i.e, the tension forces* are equal in magnitude (please correct me if I am wrong).

What I don’t understand is, how is $F_{applied}$ related to the tension force $T$ acting on block B (and block A, since the two tension forces are equal in magnitude)? Is it greater than $T$? Equal to $T$? Or smaller than $T$ in magnitude?

What is confusing to me is, since there is no friction, can the system be in equilibrium when there’s an external force $F_{applied}$ acting on Block B, no matter what magnitude the external force has?

Comment: Since the only horizontal external forces acting on the two block system is $F_{applied}$ how can possibly  they be in equilibrium?

Comment: @Bob D Ok, how is $F_{applied}$ related to $T$? If we consider block B, the horizontal forces acting on it are $T$ to the left, and $F_{applied}$ to the right. If we consider block A, the only horizontal force acting on it is $T$, to the right. Assuming that the system is not in equilibrium, how can the two blocks have the same acceleration when the number of horizontal forces acting on them are different?

Comment: Hint: the inextensible string constrains the two blocks to have the same acceleration

Comment: I understand that they are constrained to move with the same acceleration because of the inextensible string. But I am trying to understand it by analysing the forces acting on the blocks. As I just said, the number of horizontal forces acting on the two blocks is different, so it doesn’t make sense to me that they still have the same acceleration. Am I missing something?

Comment: We don’t solve homework and exercise questions. If you think about it enough the hint I gave plus the multiple application of Newton’s second law will allow you to determine the tension in the string.

Comment: It’s not a homework and exercise question, at all. I have not studied Newton’s laws yet. Currently studying different kind of forces, equilibrium, etc. So perhaps that’s why I could not understand it. It was not a homework question. I drew those blocks, vectors in the picture to make my question clearer. And thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mass A has to accelerate at the same rate as mass B, because they are connected by a string of fixed length. That means that the relative size of the net force on each object has to be in proportion to their masses, otherwise they would accelerate at different rates.

So T/(F-T) (ie the force on block A as a fraction of the force on block B) has to equal Mass A/ Mass B, from which you can work out the relationship of F and T.

You'll find that T is always less than F.

To address the question you raised in your reply to Bob 'How can the blocks have the same acceleration when they have a different number of forces acting on them?', the number of forces is irrelevant- what counts is the sum of the forces. The objects will stay in equilibrium provided that the forces applied to each are in direct proportion to their respective masses.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

@Marco Ocram answer is essentially correct. And I think you should accept it. I would just offer an additional perspective since it appears the question is not being put on hold as a "homework and exercise" question.

Since the two blocks are constrained to have the same acceleration in response to the external force $F_{applied}$ we can then apply Newton's second law to establish the acceleration of the two blocks combined as a function of the external applied force and the two masses, which will be

$$a=\frac{F_{applied}}{(M_{A}+M_{B})}$$

Now looking only at a free body diagram (FBD) of block A, the only external force acting on A is the tension in the string. Applying Newton's second law we have for the tension in the string:

$$T=M_{A}a=\frac{M_{A}F_{applied}}{(M_{A}+M_{B}}$$

Hope this adds to your understanding of Marco's answer.

Comment: It did. Studied Newton's laws, and it all seems even clearer now. Thanks